# Hiding specific columns within a custom HTML Rally app using the SDK

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I'm writing a Cardboard app using the AppSDK within a Custom HTML app.  So far, it is displaying properly (rendering all columns, column headers).

Is there a way to target and *hide* certain columns and their headers from within the Cardboard app code?  I can hide them using their CSS ID's....  However, this occurs after the app has rendered and results in a bit of an eyesore as the original app width will not resize.

TL;DR Rally Custom Kanban board (AppSDK) contains 6 User Story states. I want to hide the second and fourth states while still showing the other four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in the docs that show how to create a board that has a specific set of columns: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/specific-columns-board

In that case it's doing Owners for columns and some extra stuff with custom rendering of headers, but the guts of it is specifying the [columns](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard-cfg-columns) config to the board, which is just an array of config objects which will be used to instantiate [Rally.ui.cardboard.Column](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.Column) objects.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle; you pointed me in the correct direction. After knowing about the array, the last part was discovering `headerTpl` and `headerData: {_ScheduleState: 'enterExistingTitle'_}` were both needed to pull existing columns.  Those not referenced were then omitted.  :)  Great documentation in the SDK, btw.  Fairly straightforward.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it!